# $.ajax() is not a function, even with normal jQuery installed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

I've been trying to use ajax on my page, but when I try to use the ajax function, I get the error `$.ajax()` is not a function.

I did a little reading about this on Stackoverflow and found multiple threads that said I need to use the non-slim version of jQuery to use ajax.

However, even though I've added the full jQuery to my `<script>` tag, it still says `$.ajax()` is not a function.

Here is my code.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
<%- include('./partials/newheader.ejs', { user } ) %>



<style>


    .card {
        width: 50%;
        margin: auto;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.form-control').on('focusout', function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost:8000/fetchUser?userID=788161830857605152',
                    data: {

                    },
                    success: (response) => {
                        console.log('successful web request')
                        console.log(response.data);
                        $('.form-text').css('visibility', 'visible')
                    },
                });

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>


<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/staff/userFunctions" role="button">Click here to return to the previous page</a>

    <% if (infractions) { %>
        <div class="accordion" id="infractionsList">
            <% let iNum = 0;%>
            <% infractions.forEach(i => {%>
                <% iNum++ %>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading<%=iNum%>">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">
                            <input type="checkbox" style="float: left">
                            <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<%= iNum %>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse<%= iNum %>">
                                <% if (i.type.toLowerCase() === 'mute') {%>
                                    <!--Yellow-->
                                    <span class="badge bg-warning text-dark"><%= i.type.toLowerCase() %></span>
                                <% } else if (i.type.toLowerCase() === 'kick') {%>
                                    <!--                    red-->
                                    <span class="badge bg-danger"><%= i.type.toLowerCase() %></span>
                                <% } else if (i.type.toLowerCase() === 'warn') {%>
                                    <!--                    green-->
                                    <span class="badge bg-success text-dark"><%= i.type.toLowerCase() %></span>
                                <% } else if (i.type.toLowerCase() === 'ban') {%>
                                    <!--                    red-->
                                    <span class="badge bg-danger text-white"><%= i.type.toLowerCase() %></span>
                                <% } else { %>
                                    <span class="badge bg-secondary text-white"><%= i.type.toLowerCase() %></span>
                                <% }%>
                                    <span>
                                <%= i.infractionID %>
                            </span>
                            </button>
                        </h2>
                    </div>

                    <div id="collapse<%=iNum%>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading<%=iNum%>" data-parent="#infractionsList">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="card text-center shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Date</h5>
                                    <hr>
                                    <p class="card-text"><%= i.dateIssued %></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card text-center shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Moderator</h5>
                                    <hr>
                                    <p class="card-text"><%= i.responsibleModerator %></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card text-center shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Reason</h5>
                                    <hr>
                                    <p class="card-text"><%= i.reason %></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card text-center shadow p-3 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Notes:</h5>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                            <span class="input-group-text">Notes:</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="Notes"></textarea>
                                        <small class="form-text" style="color: #4bb543; visibility: hidden">Saved</small>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>

            <% }); %>



    <%} else { %>
        <span>
            No infractions.
        </span>
    <%}%>


</body>
</html>
```

I got the `<script` tag directly from https://code.jquery.com & used the "uncompressed" option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you cached? Is there more than one version of jQuery on the page?

Comment: Did you check the network requests to verify that the script file is giving you a 200 response?

Comment: Use the browser developer "Network" tool to see what HTTP requests are issued when you load your page.

Comment: @Pointy I just looked at the network tag I see both versions of bootstrap here. How would I prevent it from doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my "header" partial still had the slim version of jQuery and the browser was using that version.

Thanks for the help everyone!